# Split Pandas DataFrame into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I have been trying to achieve the following but is struggling. Hope someone could assist.

I currently have the following Panda Dataframe

```
Out[10]: 
0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0  15.30     396.90   4.98  24.00
0     0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65...
1     0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78...                                              
2     0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61...                                              
3     0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45...                                                                                         
4     0.06905   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  7.1470  54...                                              
5     0.02985   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.4300  58...
```

[505 rows x 1 columns]

The data is Tab delimited. I would like to covert this DataFrame to the following DataFrame format

```
      CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM    AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  \
0     0.00632  18.0   2.31     0  0.538  6.575   65.2  4.0900    1  296.0   
1     0.02731   0.0   7.07     0  0.469  6.421   78.9  4.9671    2  242.0   
2     0.02729   0.0   7.07     0  0.469  7.185   61.1  4.9671    2  242.0   
3     0.03237   0.0   2.18     0  0.458  6.998   45.8  6.0622    3  222.0   
4     0.06905   0.0   2.18     0  0.458  7.147   54.2  6.0622    3  222.0
```

[506 rows x 14 columns]

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks Much

Comment: I do not see how the numbers in the desired dataframe are related to the number in the original dataframe, and where the column names come from, and why there are only 4 columns, not 14. I do not understand the purpose of the first line of the first dataframe, either. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, the desired dataframe numbers are just samples.. my bad for not typing in clearer desired dataframe example ...  idea is to convert the original data frame of [505 rows x 1 columns] to a [506 rows x 14 columns].. many thanks

Comment: We expect your example to be minimal and self-consistent. Please fix it.

Comment: Yet, where do the column names come from?

Comment: Are you  reading this in from file? If so what format?  for a csv try 'pandas.read_csv(filepath, sep=sep='\t'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you dont change default separator (`,`) in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Solution is for tab separator:

```
names = ['CRIM','ZN','INDUS','CHAS','NOX','RM','AGE','DIS','RAD','TAX']
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\t', names = names)
```

and for whitespace separator:

```
names = ['CRIM','ZN','INDUS','CHAS','NOX','RM','AGE','DIS','RAD','TAX']
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', sep='\s+', names = names)

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names = names)
```

`names` parameter define new columns names if `csv` has no header.

Comment: The read_csv is clear.. however i want to do it within a data frame itself. Figuring out how to spilt data base on tab delimiter a single column to multiple columns. cheers

Comment: Ok, then need `df1 = df[0].str.split(expand=True)` - if column name is `0`. Or `df1 = df['0'].str.split(expand=True)` if column is string 0.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are reading data from a file (in which case `pd.read_csv()` would be a better choice, as explained in a comment to the original post), you can easily split strings into columns:

```
data = data[0].str.split().apply(pd.Series)
```

Now, add the column names with `data.columns=("CRIM","ZN","INDUS",...)`, and you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('\t')))
```

or something like that?